# PhoneGap or Native app development

Tags: android, cordova

As we are still in the design stage we have no code in place yet for our mobile app. I then stumbled on the PhoneGap tool which has left us thinking. We are both from a Java background so that is why developing using ADT/Java looked like the only option. Is the knowledge ramp up for PhoneGap steep or do you think it would be worth going with it from the start seeing as we have no existing code done yet.
We had intended to use GAE/Big table for our back end persistence.  Is this still possible if you use PhoneGap for the front end?
Also, can I assume it's possible to use Selenium to automate functional tests with phoneGap?

Our UI will just consist of Buttons,  a sprinkling of static images and Text.  Am I correct in saying the the performance drawbacks of PhoneGap should probably not be an issue in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets get going to answer your bunch of questions ?

Would I prefer you to use PhoneGap ?
Definitely Yes, The learning curve is not steep too , All you have to know is basic HTML,CSS and Javascript. Since you have also mentioned the app is simple,It would be good to use PhoneGap. Everybody know that PhoneGap sucks at Performance but since your app seems simple it wont be a problem.

Why did I recommend ?
Write once, deploy across lot of mobile platforms (If you want to support more devices)

Can Selenium Tests be run ?
Yes, You can,its just a web app. :)

Go for it, Give it a try.

If you want to support only Android or iOS or WP7 then I would prefer native development over PhoneGap because Performance matters.

Comment: So with PhoneGap,  can you do a lot of your testing on a PC/browser and only have to do some basic smoke testing on your individual mobile devices?

Comment: Yup, you can do it in browser.

Comment: But Browser behaviour will be slightly different, So testing on mobile after you use in Browser is recommended.

Answer (score 4):

I did develop both for both platform but they are completely apps and below notes are based on my experiences, I am writing for PhoneGap (I think) and you can assume android is the opposite side.

1. Cross platform, right now it is supporting all major phones (Android, IOS, WP) I am not sure it is case for you as you only tagged for Android.
2. HTML5, JS, CSS these are my area as you are Java based developers so it is up to you.
3. Not native so will be slower than native.
4. Cross browser compatibility. I think this does not need explanation especially for desktop browsers it a pain the mobiles are more easier but it is still a problem.

To answer your questions,

Yes you can use GAE/Big table for backend, with AJAX as PhoneGap uses `file://` protocol it is  supporting cross URL request.

I personally don t use PhoneGap, if the app is a game and have lots of animation going on. But in your case it is a application for listing data and responsive web might make your life easier than native app to support all screen size.

I have no idea about Selenium testing so I keep my silence for that.

And shorter answer to your for me **YES** you can use and should.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can choose between those two. There will be no serious drawbacks.

In many cases, particularly business applications which are connected to web services, choosing between Phonegap and native app is a matter of personal choice. I've met some people who prefer Phonegap and other people who avoid Phonegap, Appcelerator, or other wrapper frameworks and prefer native code.

Phonegap is easy to learn and if you need some functinalities beyond that provided by Phonegap, you can create a plugin for your app. That said, you still need to write native code for the plugin if you need to implement functionalities not provided by Phonegap.

Comment: We initially have Android platform in our sights simply because of our java backgrounds. The plan would be to eventually target the iOS platform as well